# Replication Factor 3 but ownership total only 100% rather than 300%

Tags: cassandra, replication

I'm having a strange issue with some Cassandra clusters on a set of Solaris servers.  Each of the clusters has 3 servers with its replication factor set to 3.

```
[admin@unknown] describe resolve;

WARNING: CQL3 tables are intentionally omitted from 'describe' output.
See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4377 for details.

Keyspace: resolve:
  Replication Strategy: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy
  Durable Writes: true
    Options: [replication_factor:3]
  Column Families:
```

But when we run the "nodetool ring" command it is reporting that each server owns only 33.33% of the data.

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
==========
Address       Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token
                                                                             113427455640312821154458202477256070484
10.46.36.187  rack1       Up     Normal  44.78 GB        33.33%              0
10.46.36.189  rack1       Up     Normal  39.59 GB        33.33%              56713727820156410577229101238628035242
10.46.36.190  rack1       Up     Normal  34.78 GB        33.33%              113427455640312821154458202477256070484
```

In all other clusters with the same settings they report 100% ownership.  From this it appears that the replication factor being used is still 1.  The other odd thing is that the nodetool ring is not printing out the "Replicas" line when our other clusters do.  All our clusters are currently version 1.2.5.

I've tried running the "nodetool repair" command on all the nodes and re-ran the "update keyspace" command to set the replication_factor but the ownership percentage remains unchanged.  Is there anything else I can look at or check to see why this is happening?

Edit:

This is what I normally see in my other clusters:

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
==========
Replicas: 3

Address     Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token
                                                                           113427455640312821154458202477256070484
10.50.2.65  rack1       Up     Normal  126.65 KB       100.00%             0
10.50.2.66  rack1       Up     Normal  122.15 KB       100.00%             56713727820156410577229101238628035242
10.50.2.67  rack1       Up     Normal  122.29 KB       100.00%             113427455640312821154458202477256070484
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the output. The `owns` information is just telling you, in terms of tokens, how much of the ring (%) is handled by the specific node.

The replication factor has nothing to do with this information: each node is responsible for 1/3 of the possible generated partition key tokens. Give a look at the `token` column.

If you want to verify your rf write some data with `quorum cl` , take a node out of the cluster, ask for the data with 
`quorum cl`

HTH
Carlo

Comment: What I'm still not understanding then is why is this the only cluster that reports 33%?  All of my other clusters on the same Cassandra version report 100% ownership for all three instances with a replication factor of 3.  The only time I've seen anything else is when the replication factor is 1.

Comment: Please report the token column of the other clusters

Comment: I've added the output from one of the other clusters to the question.  It's showing 100% ownership for all three nodes, and is also reporting Replicas which the Solaris system is not for some reason.  This is what I normally see in our clusters.

Comment: Same Cassandra version? Owns has changed during the year and the 100% you see is what once was called "effective ownership" which considered also the replication factor.

Comment: Yes, they are both version 1.2.5.  Also, it looks like when we add the keyspace to the nodetool ring command we see the 100% ownership on these Solaris clusters, which is still a little strange since we don't need to do that on our Linux or other Solaris clusters.

Comment: I have no clue what's going on but I remember an issue with owns values and murmur3 partitioner ...